# more than one entry saved on has_one association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, rails-models

I am trying to create a has_one association among two model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :emergency_contact
end

class EmergencyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

when i try to test it through rails console more than one entries are saved for the emergency contact model for a single user. Although when i retrieve it using User.emergency_contact only the first entry is returned. When saving how can i make it to rollback for more than one entry

Comment: Share your code you wrote in your rails console, which generates two entries instead of one ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply validate uniqueness of `user_id` column in `EmergencyContact`:

```
class EmergencyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, allow_nil: true
end
```